# How to preserve owner and group with ansible synchronize pull

Tags: ansible

I am using the ansible synchronize module to get files from a host on to the ansible controller. Is it possible to preserve the owner and group of these files? It seems to keep the permissions but the owner get changed to the ansible user.

The docs suggest the archive option but the ownership and group are overridden with the ansible user.

```
- name: copy files 
  become: no
  synchronize:
    mode: pull
    src: "/restore/backup/"
    dest: "/tmp/"
```

Comment: Do the owner and "ansible user" happen to have the same UID? If so, locally your system will display "ansible user" as the owner, but in effect the owner has been preserved

Comment: No, it could have a different uid. I ended up making my folder i wanted to copy as a .tar.gz and manually rsyncing it with the command module

Answer (score 0):

You could specify the owner:group as an option to rsync, e.g root:root

```
- name: copy files 
  become: no
  synchronize:
    mode: pull
    src: "/restore/backup/"
    dest: "/tmp/"
    rsync_opts:
    - "--chown=root:root"
```